# UITextField TapGesture doesn't respond on iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitapgesturerecognizer, ios7.1

I have a uitextfield which is programatically added to view. I need to show a UIPickerview, when i tap on that, I have added a UITapgestureRecognizer for that and user interaction also enabled. Which was working fine till IOS 7.0. But when i updated to IOS 7.1 which is not getting called.

Comment: i'm experiencing the same issue

Comment: I used the solution in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326574/uitapgesturerecognizer-on-uitextfield-no-longer-works-in-ios-7-1

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Rather than setting a tap gesture for your `textField`, you can simply set the `inputView` of your `textField` as your `pickerView`. This simply enables you to show the UIPicker when the textField is tapped or gains focus. Something like:

```
[YOUR_TEXTFIELD setInputView:YOUR_PICKER_VIEW];
```

This is just an alternative solution to your issue. You can give it a try.

Comment: But When i try it, it also won't working. I am adding the pickerview programatically. I need the same pickerview with 2 textfields

Comment: self.titlePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.frameSize.height-265, self.frameSize.width, 300)];
    self.titlePicker.tag = 1;
    self.titlePicker.dataSource = self;
    self.titlePicker.delegate = self;
    self.titlePicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [self.titlePicker setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.titlePicker selectRow:self.selTitle inComponent:0 animated:NO];
        
    [self.txtiPhoneTitle setInputView:self.titlePicker];
    [self.txtiPadTitle setInputView:self.titlePicker];

Comment: [self.titlePicker selectRow:self.selTitle inComponent:0 animated:NO];?? Are you trying to set a default selected row?

Comment: I ran your code except the above line.. It works for me.. Have you set the required delegate methods for your UIPickerView?

Comment: Yes. I need a default value.

Comment: self.selTitle contains an int value.

Comment: Okay. Have you included all the required delegate methods for your UIPickerView?