# UITapGestureRecognizer on UITextField no longer works in IOS 7.1

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer, ios7.1

I have a `UITapGestureRecognizer` attached to a `UITextField` to get a "drop down" like effect. When the `UITextField` is tapped, I present a `UIPopover` with the content. This worked like a charm pre 7.1 - Now the `UITextField` just becomes first responder, and the gesturerecognizer is totally ignored. Tried setting `delaysTouchedBegan` to YES but it didn't help.Any help?

Comment: I am facing the same issue? Want to know the reason.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why to use `UITapGestureRecognizer`, better to use `UITextFieldDelegate` methods

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{

   //Do what you need to do...

}
```

**OR**

You can wrap up your `textView` in a `UIView` and add the `UITapGestureRecognizer` on that view.

Comment: I just wrapped the textview in another view. But need to disable the user interaction of the text field.

Comment: The `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` delegate method won't be called when the text field is already the first responder. By implementing the gesture recognizer delegate as answered by @JuroSheridan it should work correctly in all cases.

Answer (score 8):

Implement the delegate method for your tap gesture

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
   return YES;
}
```

Then set yourTapGesture.delegate = self;

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Using textViewShouldBeginEditing has some issues with it. IF you have multiple UITextFields in your view controller, textViewShouldBeginEditing gets called for all the UITextFields at random times.

Answer (score 2):

Implement the delegate method of the `UITextField`:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
      // Show popover here

      return NO;
}
```